# Using com_ajax in a custom plugin to retrieve k2 items from database

Tags: plugin, joomla-3.4, ajax

I am using rsform pro to show dropdown option values from joomla database. I have 2 dropdown boxes, A list all the category name and its id while B lists all the available k2 items.

I have a jquery onchange function for A where it does an ajax request using joomla com_ajax, attached below are the codes. How can i use com_ajax to populate the B dropdown values based on the selection made on A ?

Plugin code

```
class plgAjaxK2progitems extends JPlugin
{
function onAjaxK2progitems()
{

    //$k2parid = (int) $_POST['id']; <- Old Method
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $k2parid = $input->post->get('id');

    // Prepare the database connection
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    // Run the SQL query and store it in $results
    $query
        ->select($db->quoteName(array('u.id', 'u.title', 'u.catid', 'um.name')))
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__k2_items', 'u'))
        ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__k2_categories', 'um') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('u.catid') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('um.id') . ')')
        ->where($db->quoteName('um.parent') ." = ".$db->quote($k2parid))
        ->where($db->quoteName('u.published') ." = ".$db->quote('1'))
        ->order($db->quoteName('u.id') . ' DESC');

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();

    return $results;

}
```

}

Ajax call

```
$(function() {
        $("#dept").change(function() {
        var $department = $(this).val();


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {id: $department},
            url: 'index.php?option=com_ajax&plugin=k2progitems&format=json',
            success: function(results) {

                console.log(results);                        

            }
        });
        });
    });
```

Console Log

```
Object { success: true, message: null, messages: null, data: Array[1] }
```

New Console log

```
Array[1]
0: Array[3]
 0: Object
    catid: "18"
    id: "9"
    name: "xxx"
    title: "yyy"
    __proto__: Object
 1: Object
    catid: "18"
    id: "10"
    name: "xxx"
    title: "yyy"
    __proto__: Object
 2: Object
    catid: "18"
    id: "11"
    name: "xxx"
    title: "yyy"
   __proto__: Object
```

**Update Ajax Call - Working**

```
$(function() {
        $("#dept").change(function() {
        var $department = $(this).val();


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {id: $department},
            url: 'index.php?option=com_ajax&plugin=k2progitems&format=json',
            success: function(results) {

                //console.log(results.data) <- removed this as no longer needed

               var $el = $("#progitems");
               var selectId = '#progitems';
                $el.empty(); // remove old options
                $el.append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", '').text('Please Select Item'));

                // Iterate through results - worked with results.data[0]
                $.each(results.data[0], function(key, value) {
                    if ($(selectId+' option[value="'+value.id+'"]').length == 0) {
                        $(selectId).append($('<option/>').val(value.id).text(value.title+' - '+value.name));


                    }
                });


            }
        });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please don't use `$_POST` with Joomla. Be sure to use [JInput](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) ;)

Comment: Also, instead of `console.log(results)`, could you try `console.log(results.data.html)`

Comment: i've change the $_POST to use Jinput. when i use `console.log(results.data.html)` i get Undefined

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant `console.log(results.data)`

Comment: now i see the objects but after i add `$db->setQuery($query);` somehow missed that :)

Comment: We're getting somewhere then :) if you post the current dump of the co sole log to your question, I can help you sift through it tomorrow if you still need help

Comment: sure thanks alot, added the new console log . Need to append the results as a select list value and text - based on `<option value="title">title-name</option>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need something like this:

```
var selectId = '#dropdownB'; // ID of your dropdown B 
var selected = ''; // Pass selected element here

// Iterate through results
$.each(results.data, function(key, value) {
    if ($(selectId+' option[value="'+value.id+'"]').length == 0) {
        $(selectId).append($('<option/>').val(value.id).text(value.title+' - '+value.name));

        // Add selected property
        if (key == selected) {
            $(selectId+' option[value="'+value.id+'"]').prop('selected', 'selected');
        }
    }
});

// Update Chosen if Joomla's Bootstrap is used
$(selectId).trigger("liszt:updated");
```

Comment: i am getting value "" and text as undefined-undefined . I've added my updated ajax call in the OQ

Comment: Try `$.each(results.data[0], function(key, value) {`

Answer (score 0):

use list type form field then trigger this script, edit according to your needs.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var list = jQuery('#jform_list_ID');
    var parent = list.parent();

    list.trigger('chosen:updated');
    list.ajaxChosen({
        type: 'GET',
        url: ajax_url,
        dataType: 'json'
    }, function(response) {
        var results = [];
        var data = response.data || [];
        //change accordingly to the structure you provided
         var items = data[0] || [];

        if (items) {
            jQuery.each(items, function(i, item){
                results.push({
                    value: item.value,
                    text: item.text
                });
            });
        }
        return results;
    });
});
```